# Dynamic TailwindCSS transition - how to set it on initial load?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, tailwind-css

I have a button and upon pressing it, it turns a div element transparent. It does so with a transition effect.

I saved the visibility state of the element in cookies (using js-cookie) and I'd like to keep the elements visible upon exiting and re-opening the page. It does so, but it also runs the unnecessary transition.

How should I improve my code, so that the transition only runs when I click the button, and not when the visibility state gets loaded from the cookies?

Here's my best attempt at solving it..

```
"use client";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Link from "next/link";
import Cookies from "js-cookie";

const Home = () => {
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);
  const [transition, setTransition] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    //the state of section visibility
    const visibleState = Cookies.get("visibleState");
    visibleState && setVisible(!!visibleState);

    const transitionState = Cookies.get("transitionState");
    transitionState && setTransition(!!transitionState);

    return () => {
      Cookies.set("transitionState", "false");
    };
  }, []);

  const handleToggleVisibility = () => {
    Cookies.set("visibleState", String(!visible));
    setTransition(!transition);
    setVisible(!visible);
  };

  return (
    <main className="flex h-5/6 flex-col justify-between">
      {/* Who section */}
      <section>
        <div className="flex h-1/6 items-center justify-center text-3xl font-light">
          <span className="text-slate-500">{"< "}</span>
          <button onClick={handleToggleVisibility}>&nbsp;who?&nbsp;</button>
          <span className="text-slate-500">{" />"}</span>
        </div>

        <div
          className={
            "mt-20 flex h-2/6 flex-col items-center justify-center gap-[1px] text-3xl font-light transition-all duration-700 " +
            (visible ? "opacity-100" : "opacity-0") +
            (transition ? " transition-all duration-700" : "")
          }
        >
          <Link
            href="/dev"
            className="mx-auto w-1/4 border border-black p-4 text-center transition-all duration-300 hover:border-slate-500 active:bg-slate-800"
          >
            Software developer
          </Link>
          <Link
            href="/books"
            className="mx-auto w-1/4 border border-black p-4 text-center transition-all duration-300 hover:border-slate-500 active:bg-slate-800"
          >
            Reader
          </Link>
          <Link
            href="dreams"
            className="mx-auto w-1/4 border border-black p-4 text-center transition-all duration-300 hover:border-slate-500 active:bg-slate-800"
          >
            Dreamer
          </Link>
        </div>
      </section>

      {/* Contact footer */}
      <p className="flex items-center justify-center p-6 text-2xl tracking-widest">
        <span className="text-slate-500">{"<"}</span>
        <Link href={"/contact"}>&nbsp;Contact&nbsp;</Link>
        <span className="text-slate-500">{"/>"}</span>
      </p>
    </main>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues with your code.

1. You set the transition classes unconditionally. Modify your container classes as follows.

```
<div
  className={
    "mt-20 flex h-2/6 flex-col items-center justify-center gap-[1px] text-3xl font-light " +
    (visible ? "opacity-100" : "opacity-0") +
    (transition ? " transition-all duration-700" : "")
  }
>
```

2. You do not need to store the transition state in cookies. You can simplify your effect and `handleToggleVisibility` function as follows.

```
useEffect(() => {
  setVisible(Cookies.get("visibleState") === "true");
}, []);

const handleToggleVisibility = () => {
  Cookies.set("visibleState", String(!visible));
  setVisible(!visible);
  setTransition(true);
};
```

Comment: Ooooh I see, thank you! I tunnel visioned and over-complicated the code for no reason. It works!